Can't remember film name with weapons dropping from corridors and gunfights
I don't remember much about this film as I watched it when I was young, so it must have been produced before 2005.
All I remember is people, probably bad guys, are kind of trapped in a building (the majority of them look surprised when the "game" starts). It could also be a facility, but not outside.
Someone (not visible on screen) speaks in a microphone and everyone can hear him through microphones. Also, people are not all located in the same place in the building. Shortly after his speech, weapons drop from corridors (literally). It's also raining bullets and empty magazines. I remember that people try to fill their magazines ASAP so they can shoot others quickly.
No idea how the film ends, if a good/bad guy "wins" by killing all others or if he/she/they find the speaker at the beginning.
Anyone familiar with these scenes?

Sounds like Mean Guns (1997) 

A gangster boss (Ice-T) has a list of about 100 people who have screwed up at one point or another. Rather than outright killing them, he decides to have a little fun by putting all of them together in a high security prison, unarmed, and dumping bucketfulls of guns, ammo, and baseball bats on them and letting them kill each other. The final three who survive are given a prize of 10 million dollars. Let chaos reign




